# Concat / Substring

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 12345 || 0011 from dual;
```

The result in Oracle is coming out as 1234511. It is removing the zeros.

```
SELECT length(12345 || 0011) from dual;
```

The result in Oracle is coming out as 7. It is not counting zeros.

I was thinking of doing lpad but the problem is 0011 passed above as a number. In reality it can come as 2, 3 or 4 digits number in the procedure.

How can I write a query where it will not remove zeros when concatenating or finding length?

Thanks

---

This is from the procedure...

```
SELECT  Count(programID)
INTO pCount
FROM program
WHERE SUBSTR(PrefixA || PrefixB, 1, (LENGTH(72776 || 0906))) =   72776 ||     
0906
or PrefixA || PrefixB = SUBSTR(72776 || 0906, 1, LENGTH(PrefixA || PrefixB))
;
```

0906 and 72776 comes via the procedure call. It can be a two, three or four digits number. For Example: 090, 08, 770, 0906.

If the above number is not in the program table then it should produce a 'Zero" count in the PCOUNT but the above query is truncating 0 and hence forming the number as 72776906 and that combination does exist in the database.

Comment: Concat integer values, why?

Comment: "In reality it can come as 2, 3 or 4 digits number in the procedure" - sorry, but that doesn't really make sense. Either you're getting a number (in that case you cannot have leading zeroes), or you're getting a string (in that case, you already have the string representation that you need). I guess you need to provide more sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 4):

`0011` is a number literal; the number `11` which is the same as `011`, `0011`, etc and any leading zeroes are not preserved as they have no semantic value (as a number). It is not a string; string literals have surrounding single quotes (i.e. `'0011'`) and will preserve all the characters.

If you want to preserve leading zeroes then use strings:

```
SELECT '12345' || '0011' FROM DUAL
```

Or convert the numbers to zero-padded strings:

```
SELECT LPAD( 12345, 5, '0' ) || LPAD( 11, 4, '0' ) FROM DUAL;
```

*(Note: if the input is longer than the padded size then `LPAD` will show the most-significant digits until it reaches the padded size)*

Or

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( 12345, '00000' ) || TO_CHAR( 11, '0000' ) FROM DUAL;
```

*(Note: if the input is longer than the format mask's size then `TO_CHAR` will not show the numbers but will show `#` characters instead)*

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has to_char() if you always want 4 digits

```
select trim(to_char(12345,'99999999999') -- use as many 9's as the max length of field1
     || to_char(0011,'0000') -- This will always pad this to 4 digits
from dual
```